# Are there such things as "root objects"?

Tags: objects

For some reason, Shywu's model has what I can only assume is a "root object". After I exported her model as an FBX and imported her into Blender, the last object I placed/edited (an eye) was thought to be the main thing that moves everything.[image: the idle black dot is supposed to be her left eye]

Comment: hello, I'm not sure your question is very clear, if you need an object that allows you to move some other ones, parent all the objects to this one. The parent object can also be an empty.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Also, I don't really want the eye to be the main thing controlling the model. I'd rather it be the body (the sphube).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make an object the parent of several objects, select the objects, then, at last, the parent, and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> *(Set Parent To)* > *Object*. You can also create an empty, <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *(Add)* > *Empty* > *Plain Axes*, and make it the parent of your object with the same *Set Parent To* operation. To deparent, select the object and <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Clear Parent*. You can know what's the parent of an object if you select it, go in the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Relations* > *Parent*.

Does it answer?